# Rails 4 + Devise: set default root route for authenticated users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise, rails-routing

I have done some research and seen that this question has already been addressed several times, in different places:

- [Devise with rails 4 authenticated root route not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997874/devise-with-rails-4-authenticated-root-route-not-working)
- [Different '/' root path for users depending if they are authenticated (using devise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725094/different-root-path-for-users-depending-if-they-are-authenticated-using-dev)
- [Authenticated Route Constraints](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1147)
- [Rails Tip #5: Authenticated Root and Dashboard Routes With Devise](http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-5-authenticated-root-and-dashboard-routes-with-devise/)

I tried to follow the examples given in the links above and came up with the following solution, in my `routes.rb` file:

```
root to: 'pages#home'

devise_for :users, :path => 'account', controllers: { registrations: "registrations", confirmations: "confirmations" }

authenticated :user do
  root 'calendars#index', as: :authenticated_root
end
```

The goal here is to direct `unauthenticated` users to the regular `home` page of the website, while `authenticated` users will go to their dashboard, inside the app, i.e. the `calendars#index` route, defined as follows in my routes:

```
calendars GET    /calendars(.:format)                        calendars#index
```

However, when I log in as a user, and visit `http://localhost:3000/`, I keep landing on the regular `home` page of the website, instead of the user's dashboard inside the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As in the first link you include, I would try wrapping the unauthenticated `root` route.

Comment: Thanks, that worked indeed. Feel free to submit this as an answer, and I will be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `routes.rb` so that the unauthenticated `root` route is wrapped, just like the authenticated one:

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'account', controllers: { registrations: "registrations", confirmations: "confirmations" }

authenticated :user do
  root 'calendars#index', as: :authenticated_root
end

unauthenticated :user do
  root 'pages#home', as: :unauthenticated_root
end
```